# Qt signal with an enum as a parameter

Tags: qt, enums

I'm trying to pass an enum as a value to a slot in my program, but I'm having some problems.  In my header file I've created the enum:

```
Q_ENUMS(button_type);
enum button_type {button_back, button_up, button_down, button_ok};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(button_type);
```

And in my .cpp file I'm trying to pass it to a slot:

```
QObject::connect(buttons->ui.pushButton_back, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(input_handler(button_back)));
```

But when I compile the code I get:

```
Object::connect: No such slot main_application::input_handler(button_back) in main_application.cpp:44
Object::connect:  (sender name:   'pushButton_back')
Object::connect:  (receiver name: 'main_applicationClass')
```

It compiles and works fine if I don't pass an argument to input_handler.

I've also read that I should be calling qRegisterMetaType, but I can't seem to get the syntax correct.  Here's what I tried:

```
qRegisterMetaType<button_type>("button_type");
```

but I get this error:

```
main_application.h:15:1: error: specializing member ‘::qRegisterMetaType<button_type>’ requires ‘template<>’ syntax
```

Can anyone shed some light on this for me?

Thanks!

Marlon

Comment: Nothing about this ”specializing member ...” error...?

Answer (score 3):

Signal and Slot need to have the same parameters. What you want is a QSignalMapper.

**edit:**
Here is an example from an application of mine. It creates 10 menu actions that each are connected to the same slot `gotoHistoryPage` but each called with a different `int` value.

```
m_forwardMenu = new QMenu();
for(int i = 1; i<=10; i++)
{
    QAction* action = m_forwardMenu->addAction(QString("%1").arg(i));
    m_forwardActions.push_back(action);
    m_signalMapper->setMapping(action, i);
    connect(action, SIGNAL(triggered()), m_signalMapper, SLOT(map()));
}
ui.forwardButton->setMenu(m_forwardMenu);
connect(m_signalMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(int)), this, SLOT(gotoHistoryPage(int)));
```

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the `SLOT()` macro a value when it's expecting a type. More fundamentally this doesn't make much sense anyway as what you're struggling to achieve is to pass the slot a constant. Why not just use `button_back` in the slot function directly?

You *can* define a slot which takes a `button_type` *value*, but then you'd need to connect it to a signal that passes one as a parameter.

What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

```
Object::connect: No such slot main_application::input_handler(button_back)
```

Of course, there is, because signature is `main_application::input_handler(button_type)`, and `button_back` is a value, not type. And even you make right signature, you will not be able to connect that signal and slot due to their signature mismatch.

Also, you can always use `QObject::sender()` function to get known, what button was pressed.