# QObject::connect() with enum parameters

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to use `QObject::connect()` with enum parameters. I got this message...

```
QObject::connect: Incompatible sender/receiver arguments
        Calendar::calendarExceptionThrown(Calendar*,ExceptionType)
   --> CalendarDBView::handleCalendarException(Calendar*,Calendar::ExceptionType)
```

The connect code is:

```
 connect(cal, SIGNAL(calendarExceptionThrown(Calendar*,ExceptionType)),
         this, SLOT(handleCalendarException(Calendar*,Calendar::ExceptionType)));
```

From what I've read, I figured I needed to add this to the class definition of `Calendar`:

```
Q_ENUMS(ExceptionType)
```

I added this to `main.cpp`:

```
qRegisterMetaType<Calendar::ExceptionType>("ExceptionType");
```

I'm still getting the warning message. [This related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030601/qt-signal-with-an-enum-as-a-parameter) didn't solve my issue. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you post the line where's you're doing the connect? Did you try to register the type as `Calendar::ExceptionType`?

Comment: The line is `connect(cal, SIGNAL(calendarExceptionThrown(Calendar*,ExceptionType)), this, SLOT(handleCalendarException(Calendar*,Calendar::ExceptionType)));`.

Comment: You need to use Calendar::ExceptionType in both the SIGNAL and SLOT macros.  You might also need to make sure that's how it is in the declarations of your signal and slot.  It's a weakness in Qt - it uses strings for the signal/slot signatures, so it has trouble resolving scopes.

Comment: Wow, that's all kinds of confusing. You're right, it does work if I use the full name. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe if you simply change ExceptionType to Calendar::ExceptionType in the SIGNAL part of your connect, it will fix the problem. moc expects the strings for both the SIGNAL and SLOT to match.

Comment: Dan's comment above (which I didn't see until posting my answer) explains things a little better than I did.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be very consistent with your signal and slots declarations, and with what you put in the `SIGNAL` and `SLOT` macros. `moc` isn't a full C++ compiler, it's just a relatively smart parser. But ultimately the signal and slot names are just strings.

For example, this "works":

```
#include <QtCore>

class A: public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        enum MyEnum { e0 };

    public:
        A(QObject *parent=0): QObject(parent) {
            connect(this, SIGNAL(fire(A::MyEnum)), this, SLOT(foo(A::MyEnum)));
        }

    public slots:
        void foo(A::MyEnum) {
            qDebug() << "In slot A::foo()";
        }
    signals:
        void fire(A::MyEnum);
    public:
        void test() { emit fire(e0); }
};
```

It would also work if you remove *all* the `A::` qualifiers for `MyEnum`. But it will fail if you leave some in but remove others.
So qualify all the names if these signals/slots need to be visible/accessible outside your class.